# Control polling frequency with Jenkins Git polling + hook

Tags: git, jenkins, hudson, githooks

After experiencing many failures in Jenkins Git plugin native polling, and reading [Kohsuke blogpost](http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/), I've integrated git hook in our Stash server that triggers any Jenkins job that uses git repository and has polling configured.

Problem is:

- Git hooks triggers my job on each commit
- I have some expensive configurations that should only run once a day (poll changes once a day).

What can I do?

Comment: One possible but not optimal solution is to use timer in those expensive configurations, but can also cause those expensive jobs to run even if there are no changes - so I really rather to avoid it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With newer version of Jenkins, you can disable jobs from listening to post-commit hooks:

Open job configuration, got to Git configuration.

Under `Additional Behaviours`, click `add` and select `Don't trigger a build on commit notifications`.

Now your job only starts when actual polling for changes occurs.

If you use GitPlugin Version >= 2.0.3, you can also check "Ignore post-commit hooks" under the SCM Trigger configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer - just what I needed! :)